# Force Download a file using an Ajax request or Task

Tags: plugin-development, request

The following code doesn't seem to work when called using an Ajax or Task but it does work otherwise:

```
craft()->request->sendFile($file, IOHelper::getFileContents($file), array('forceDownload' => true));
```

I was wondering, Is it not possible to force download a file using an Ajax or Task?

Any help much appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to use Craft's [`HttpRequestService->sendFile()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#sendFile-detail) for this.  But there are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post) of [non-Craft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data) of [doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request), depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I would definitely have a look at them and post here which method I went with.